# How to integrate OptaPlanner

Tags: java, node.js, express, optaplanner, constraint-programming

I'm working on a node.js project for a timetable platform where professors can input preferences. Need help a tool (ex. integrating optaplanner ) to solve complex constraint programming issues efficiently.

Any insights, resources, or documentation recommendations are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Considering the implementation of a microservice, but exploring simpler alternatives for a more straightforward integration.

Answer (score 1):

[Timefold Solver](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork) (a fully compatible fork of OptaPlanner) has a wide range of [quickstarts](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts) which show you how to create a backend Java service for the solver, and provides a demo UI to access that service. [Timefold documentation](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/quickstart/overview/overview-quickstarts) takes you through all the important parts.